# OwnCloud: see file sharing access

Tags: logging, owncloud, sharing

I have shared a folder with some files using the ["share link"](https://doc.owncloud.com/server/9.0/user_manual/files/access_webgui.html#file-controls) feature.

How can I see whether this folder was accessed by the recipient of that link?

Note: The server I use has Version ownCloud 9.0.1 (stable). I have both an admin role and a user role there. I shared the link with the user role.

A [quick search](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=owncloud%20share%20link%20access%20person&t=ffab&ia=web) (on `owncloud share link access person`)
did not show up anything significant to see access, but only about sharing.

Comment: Check in your data directory for the `syslog.log` and `ownCloud.log` files. The logging level can be changed. In the enterprise version you should be able even to preempt single user to access too... Give it a look to the forum [ [1](https://forum.owncloud.org/viewtopic.php?t=23388),[2](https://forum.owncloud.org/viewtopic.php?t=4687)] or search for _logging app_... give it a look to nextcloud too (to try to overcome some _enterprise only_ feature limitations). The magic word to use as keyword  is `log` (you may try `logging` too). `;-)` Let me know.

Comment: @Hastur, why don't you write this as an answer? As stated, I prefer a GUI solution, but if none is available yours may be the best one still.

Comment: Added an answer with some information more, even if some of them (as the link you provided) refer to to version 10...

Comment: Thanks @Hastur I updated the docs link to version 9, which I refer to

Answer (score 1):

### A First glimpse

Check in your data directory for the `syslog.log` and `ownCloud.log` files.
The logging level can be changed <sup>[[0](https://doc.owncloud.org/server/9.0/admin_manual/configuration_server/logging_configuration.html)]</sup>.
You may find useful to see in the forum some pages <sup>[[f1](https://forum.owncloud.org/viewtopic.php?t=23388),[f2](https://forum.owncloud.org/viewtopic.php?t=4687)]</sup>.
You may search for "+owncloud +app +log +file +audit".
Since some finding refer to the payment version, you may search for nextcloud solution too.

## A second not definitive glimpse

Owncloud seems to allow a level of Logging and Auditing <sup>[[1](https://owncloud.com/manage-control-files/)]</sup>...

> #### Logging and Auditing
>
> Visibility of all file sharing is critical for maintaining regulatory and judiciary compliance.  The ability to maintain an audit trail and set alert conditions ensure IT will be able to support the business requirements of compliance while providing enhanced productivity for employees.
>
> Not only does ownCloud allow IT to control each user’s permissions, but it also **enables a full audit trail - allowing IT to understand how, when and where data is accessed and shared.** Admins can log account level activities such as logins to ownCloud as well as what users do with files on the server. This provides basic information needed for compliance reporting and auditing of ownCloud usage, and the tools to actively follow file sharing activities.

Even if it seems only to log user actions and actions on files. For this it exists a graphical app too <sup>[[2](https://doc.owncloud.org/server/9.0/admin_manual/enterprise_logging/enterprise_logging_apps.html)]</sup>, even if available for the enterprise version only.

You stated that you want to share the file with the *"share link feature"* that allows <sup>[[3](https://doc.owncloud.com/server/user_manual/files/public_link_shares.html)]</sup>:

> With ownCloud X (10.0), we introduced the ability to create multiple public links per file or folder. This offers a lot of flexibility for creating **different kinds of share links for a single file** or folder, such as **different passwords**, expiry dates, and permissions.

So you should be able to have a log for each password.
You may try.